# Why does Tiny Ron wear a prosthetic face mask as Lothar?

Tags: adaptations, the-rocketeer-1991

In the 1991 adaptation of the comic The Rocketeer, Tiny Ron plays Lothar. The face prosthetic used is almost comical, but looks like it's obviously meant to make Lothar look 'monstrous' by exaggerating the effects of [Acromegaly](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acromegaly) - large square chin and jaw, wrinkled face, large flat nose.

[image: still from the movie cropped to show only Lothar's face in detail]

Tiny Ron doesn't tend to wear this for his other roles, and although I've seen references saying that the character was meant to resemble Rondo Hatton (who I find out now, *does* have Acromegaly) I can't find any concrete reference to that being deliberate or specific.

Is the character a reference to the comics or was it deliberately referencing the 1930s/40s actor?

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer:

I have found many internet references to Tiny Ron being made up to resemble Rondo Hatton. It is also claimed the character Lothar is from the Rocketeer comics where Lothar's look was based on Rondo Hatton.

As I remember, the statement that Lothar was designed to look like Rondo Hatton was part of the publicity for *The Rocketeer* when it was released in 1991.   I may have read the statement in *Starlog* and/or *Cinefantstique*, and possibly a person connected with the production might be quoted in such an artile.

There is a biography "Rondo Hatton: Beauty Within the Brute" (BearManor Media, 2019) by Scott Gillinghouse.

Joe Johnston, director of *The Rocketeer* is still alive.

Rick baker who created the make up for Lothar, is still alive.

So there are a number of possible lines of reseach.

Long Answer:

It is possible that some of the following statements might be considered sufficient proof that the make up of Lothar in *The Rocketeer* (1991) was based on the look of Rondo Hatton.

According to the IMDB:

> His appearance has endured far longer than even the best of his films. His likeness was the basis for the villain in The Rocketeer (1991). Also, in recent years the Rondo Hatton Classic Horror Awards, awarded each year for the best in horror research, appreciation and film restoration, uses his name and consists of a statuette based on the mammoth bust of Hatton as the Creeper, seen in Universal's House of Horrors (1946). More information about the "Rondos" can be found at [www.rondoaward.com](http://www.rondoaward.com).

https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0369061/bio?ref_=nm_ov_bio_sm

> Lothar (Tiny Ron) was made-up to look like Rondo Hatton, who played similar characters in "B" movies, which inspired this movie. Ron can be seen out of make-up in a cameo, as one of two good old boys. He gapes as his companion marvels at the "Big gopher!

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102803/trivia/?ref_=tt_trv_trv

Wikipedia says:

> Hatton's physical likeness inspired the Lothar character in Dave Stevens's 1980s Rocketeer Adventure Magazine stories, and in Disney's 1991 film version, The Rocketeer, in which the character is played by actor Tiny Ron in prosthetic make-up.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rondo_Hatton

> Besides pulp characters, actors of the 1940s and 1950s have also visually inspired two characters: Lothar, the villain in "Cliff's New York Adventure", is based on the likeness of acromegalic horror movie star Rondo Hatton;[12] and Cliff Secord's girlfriend Betty is modeled after "Queen of Pinups" Bettie Page.[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rondo_Hatton)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocketeer

> The actor who played Lothar in the movie was heavily made up to resemble actor Rondo Hatton, who unfortunately did look like that in real life. Hatton suffered from acromegaly, and appeared in movies like PEARL OF DEATH and HOUSE OF HORRORS where his character "the Creeper" was a pyschotic killer who broke the backs of his victims (as does Lothar).

https://dr-hermes.livejournal.com/470134.html

> Rondo Hatton’s legacy lives on. Legendary makeup effects wizard, Rick Baker, recreated Hatton’s face with prosthetic makeup, bringing the Creeper back to life as the menacing thug, Lothar, in “The Rocketeer” (1991). Amok Time Toys created a 12 inch action figure of the Creeper for the collector’s market, and of course, the Rondo Hatton Classic Horror Awards keep that unforgeable mug in the conscious of horror fans everywhere.

https://louisvillehalloween.com/meet-the-creeper-who-is-rondo-hatton/

> Comic-Book Fantasy Casting: Characters that look like Hatton have appeared in Swamp Thing (as a psychic), The Rocketeer (as a homicidal former circus strongman) and Judge Dredd (a crooked lawyer).
>
> Comic-Book Fantasy Casting: Characters that look like Hatton have appeared in Swamp Thing (as a psychic), The Rocketeer (as a homicidal former circus strongman) and Judge Dredd (a crooked lawyer).

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Creator/RondoHatton